# Add-in makes Excel crash when starting minimized

Tags: c#, process, excel-2007, minimize, xla

I start Excel from within my C# WinForms application using `Process.Start(...)` (this has a reason). I want to start it in background, without distracting the user, so I try to start it minimized or hidden. In both cases, I experience a very weird behavior:

After some seconds, **Excel restores the window (even makes it visible if it's hidden) and then crashes** saying: "Microsoft Office Excel has encountered a problem and needs to close. (Win XP crash message.)"

The same thing happens if I start Excel manually by double-clicking its Shortcut Icon on the Desktop and then just switch to another application window immediately, such that **the Excel window loses focus during startup.**

The problem appears only if any of the **XLA add-in contains a UserForm**. If I remove the UserForm, the problem disappears. If I remove the add-in, the problem disappears.

**Any help is appreciated, as long as it is**

- An explanation of why this happens
- Something I can change in the add-in
- A way how to work around this bug *(without using COM)*
- *Not* a suggestion to use COM. ([See here to understand why I don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719579/shellex-starting-excel-minimized-or-hidden).)
- *Not* an advice to update Excel (I can't)

---

Steps to reproduce:

- Start Excel 2007 with an empty workbook.
- Save As...

  - File Type: Excel 2003 Add-in (*.xla)
  - Location: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\foobar.xla
- Alt + F11 (open VBA editor)
- Add a UserForm to the project.
- Save and Quit Excel
- Start Excel and then immediately click on the Firefox or whatever tab in the taskbar to activate any window other than Excel.
- Wait and watch Excel start, until it crashes.
- ### After restarting Excel it says:

  > Excel experienced a serious problem with the 'foobar' add-in. If you have seen this message multiple times, you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this add-in?

---

Details/Findings:

- Excel version: 12.0.6535.5002, SP2 MSO 12.0.6425.1000
- 0xA3 reported in his comment he could reproduce it on 32 bit machine with Excel 12.0.6535.5002, SP2 MSO 12.0.6535.5002
- I've tried with a 2007 add-in (XLAM). The same problem, except that it even crashes if it doesn't contain any UserForms.
- 0xA3 reported that on his 64 bit machine it worked, however Excel still pops up unexpectedly (but doesn't crash). The same holds for 2 machines of my testers so far.

This is the code I wanted to use in C# (note that the problem can be reproduced completely independent of any C# app, see above).

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("excel.exe") 
    { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized });
```

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this, but I have no idea yet for a workaround.

Comment: @0xA3: What Excel version do *you* have? I've added mine to my question.

Comment: @chiccodoro. I was not able to reproduce this error. I'm using VS2008 .NET 3.5 SP1, OS is Windows XP SP3, Excel 2007 version is `12.0.6504.5001`.

Comment: Seems to get nasty... I have to boxes, one Win7 64-bit, one Win7 32-bit, both with Excel 12.0.6535.5002, SP2 MSO 12.0.6535.5002. On the 32-bit OS Excel is crashing, on the 64-bit OS there is no problem. Looks like this is either a configuration problem or related to the OS. However, the Excel window is activated and restored in the functioning case despite  `ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized`.

Comment: Uh oh, seems like a bug in Excel or so. I fear no one will be able to help me out...

Comment: Have you tried using COM automation with the workaround described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213489

Comment: @0xA3, yes I do. It's not feasible if you don't know the add-ins. I tried looping through all the add-ins and unload then load them, but it didn't work. In contrary, it messed up the add-ins so they didn't work properly anymore afterwards...